# Exceptions - basic exercise

Tags: c#

I have the following exercise:
Define a class named circle that accepts objects of type point, and calculates their distance from the center of the circle. If the point is outside the circle should be sent notices of exception.

This is my code:

```
class Point
{
    protected int x,y;
    public Point(int x,int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
class Circle : Point
{
    public Circle(Point p,int radius):base(3,5)
    {

    }

}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    }
}
```

I don't know what I have to do in the circle class, how can I know if the point is in the circle or not? 
Thanks everyone.

Comment: I don't see why you've made Circle *derive from* Point here... it's meant to have a method which *accepts* values of type Point, as far as I can see....

Comment: It's not, I'm in holiday. I'm trying to learn this.

Comment: @Jon: I don't need to derive the Point/

Comment: @Jon: I just need to do something like that?class Circle
    {
        public Circle(Point p,int radius)
        {

        }
    }

Comment: @Rich: That looks more appropriate, yes... except you'll then want to remember the centre and radius, of course.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *Define a class named circle that accepts objects of type point, and calculates their distance from the center of the circle. If the point is outside the circle should be sent notices of exception.*

**Inheritance vs. composition:** First, it seems wrong that your class `Circle` derives from `Point`, just because you need an `x` and `y` coordinate pair for your circle, too. Remember that inheritance usually models "is-a" relationships. But circles are not points. Rather, it could be said that they can be defined through a point (the center) and a radius. Thus it would be more logical to use composition ("has-a" relationship):

```
class Circle
{
    Point  center;
    double radius;
}
```

**When to use exceptions (and when not to)**: Second, I hope that whoever gave you the exercise didn't actually mean to `throw` an exception just because your distance-calculating method got a `Point` that lies outside the circle. I would consider this use of exceptions invalid. Exceptions ought to be used in circumstances where some condition occurs that your code cannot properly deal with. However, calculating a distance between two points can never fail (unless perhaps for weird floating-point issues like overflow or underflow):

```
double DistanceFromCentreTo(Point p)
{
    // See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem:
    return Math.Sqrt((center.x - p.x) * (center.x - p.x) + 
                     (center.y - p.y) * (center.y - p.y));
}
```

If suddenly such a method threw an exception, many users of your code might consider this unlogical. Why should that method go beyond what its name suggests, and throw an exception just because the distance is greater than `radius`?

It would be more advisable IMO to introduce a second method:

```
bool LiesWithinCircle(Point p)
{
    return DistanceFromCentreTo(p) <= radius;
}
```

Now you have two methods that both do just what most people would expect, don't throw unexpected exceptions, and still offer all the functionality that you'll most likely need.

---

**P.S.:** Reading my answer many days later, it suddenly strikes me that it would be better still to define the two methods shown above on the `Point` class instead, e.g.:

```
double DistanceToCenterOf(this Point p, Circle c) { … }
bool   LiesWithin        (this Point p, Circle c) { … }
```

... which results in easier-to-understand code; e.g. `somePoint.LiesWithin(someCircle)` instead of `someCircle.LiesWithinCircle(somePoint)`.

Comment: @stakx Thanks alot for your very well explanation, I will try to do the exercise now, btw I'm working with a book.

Comment: @stakx I've tried to do it, and this is the code now: http://pastebin.com/5mbHaxZ3 my question is, if I'm getting only the Point p and not the center Point how can the function calc the distance? Thanks.

Comment: @Rich, first, you've got a typo in your current code. You need to do `Math.Sqrt(… + …)`, not `Math.Sqrt(… - …)`. Then, to answer your question, you are right that to calculate a distance, you need two points. And you've got these: `p` (an argument to the `Distance…` method), and `center` (a field of your `Circle` class). But of course you need to initialize `center`, e.g. by passing the center point to `Circle`'s constructor: `class Circle { … public Circle(Point center, double radius) { this.center = center; this.radius = radius; } …`

Comment: @Rich, you're welcome. Just as a reminder, since you're a fairly new member here on Stack Overflow: If an answer has solved your problem, you can mark it with a tick. (See also the **[FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)**, "accepted answer".)

Answer (score 2):

> how can I know if the point is in the
>   circle or not?

1. Calculate distance between the point and the center.
2. If it is greater than the radius, then it's outside.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but do you have any idea what I need to do in the circle constructor?

Answer (score 1):

This will tell you if you are in the circle or not:

```
class Point
{
    protected int x,y;
    public Point(int x,int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int X { get { return x; } }
    public int Y { get { return y; } }
}
```

in circle's constructor :

```
public Circle(Point p,int radius):base(3,5)
{

    if ( Math.Sqrt( Math.Pow( p.X - this.X, 2.0) + Math.Pow( p.Y - this.Y, 2.0)) > radius )
       throw new ArgumentException("This point is outside the circle");
}
```

Comment: This assumes that you have derived from Point so that the centre of the circle is at the point. As Jon Skeet has pointed out, this is bad form. inheritance models an is-a relationship, and a circle isn't a point.

Comment: @Rich : no. Wrote something that was half a variable, half a property. Have edited.

Answer (score 1):

Should be something like this, assuming you ask only about exceptions and already know the logic involved in calculating distance:

```
class Circle
{
    public Circle(Point p,int radius)
    {
        //code to construct the circle here..
    }

    public double DistanceFromCenter(Point p)
    {
        if (p is outside circle)
            throw new Exception("Point " + p + " is outside the circle");
        //calculate the distance and return it...
    }
}
```

Comment: Two things that I would add to your (good) answer: **(1)** `DistanceFromCenter` should probably return a floating point number, not an `int`. **(2)** It should be added that the use of exceptions in this case could be regarded as misplaced. `DistanceFromCenter` can always return a valid result, even if a point lies further away from the circle center than the circle's radius, and exceptions might be unexpected. It seems wiser to add another method, `bool IsInsideCircle(Point p)`. Exceptions ought to be used where something unexpected happens that your code cannot deal with.

Comment: I don't think DistanceFromCenter should return int. More like double to me.

Comment: @stakx thanks, good points.. maybe even worth separate Answer as the OP is pretty vague in the first place. :)

Answer (score 0):

Circle with radius R on the origin is `x^2+y^2=R^2` the point is in circle if x^2+y^2**<=**R^2